# Does Json.Encode() use JavaScriptSerializer Class to serialize

Tags: c#, json, razor, javascriptserializer

Does the `Json.Encode()` Helper use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class to encode a string to json?

I am getting a circular reference exception when using `Json.Encode(Model)` even though my class properties that are being serialized have the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute.

My only guess is that maybe the `Json.Encode()` helper doesn't use the JavaScriptSerializer to serialize to json but I can't find the documentation anywhere on msdn.

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

Here's an example of one of the models that has a property that should not be serialized...

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace RobotDog.Entities {
    public class Character {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

        [ScriptIgnore]
        public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Json.Encode` most likely uses the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace which differs from the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In my controller I query my repository to get an `IEnumerable<MyModel>` and then in the view I serialize the model because I'm using KnockoutJS for the UI.

Comment: I should also mention that my entities are in a separate class library project from my web project.

Comment: In that case, in the action of your controller you could `return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` where "jsonData" is an array with the proper json structure that you need. I also use something similar to get data for populating a jqGrid in a razor view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the Json.Encode() Helper use the JavaScriptSerializer class to encode a string to json?

Yes.

From the source code:

```
private static readonly JavaScriptSerializer _serializer = Json.CreateSerializer();

public static string Encode(object value)
{
  DynamicJsonArray dynamicJsonArray = value as DynamicJsonArray;
  if (dynamicJsonArray != null)
    return Json._serializer.Serialize((object) (object[]) dynamicJsonArray);
  else
    return Json._serializer.Serialize(value);
}
```

where `JavaScriptSerializer` is `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`

also to assist your issue see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263987/circular-references-and-scriptignore-problems)

Comment: Could someone put in or comment with a link to the source quoted above?  I presume that Json.Decode<T> also uses JavaScriptSerializer, but presumptions can get one into trouble so I'd like to check the source for Decode as well.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I found this - perhaps someone can comment if it's the correct source: https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/Json.cs

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx

according to the above link Json.Encode uses system.web.helpers.

What does your Model contain?

Also, are you sure that [ScriptIgnore] will ignore what you have it assigned to?

Comment: Yeah I've looked at the msdn docs, and it wasn't really that helpful. I've added one of the entities that has a property that shouldn't be serialized.